# Justification on why a set is $\mathbb{Q}$-basis of a number field

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Assume that $f(x) = \sum_{j=0}^{n} a_{j}x^{j} \in\mathbb{Z}[x]$ be an irreducible polynomial and $\theta$ be one of the roots of $f(x)$ and $K = \mathbb{Q}(\theta)$. I want to show that the following set of elements $w_{1}, w_{2}, \ldots, w_{n}$ is a basis of $K$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

$$w_{1} = 1\\ w_{2} = a_{n}\theta\\ w_{3} = a_{n}\theta^{2} + a_{n-1}\theta \\ \vdots \\ w_{n} = a_{n}\theta^{n-1} + a_{n-1}\theta^{n-2} + \ldots + a_{3}\theta^{2} + a_{2}\theta $$

Any element of $K$ is of the form $\big( b_{1}\theta^{n-1} + b_{2}\theta^{n-2} + \ldots + b_{n-1}\theta + b_{n} \big)$ with $b_{1}, \ldots, b_{n} \in\mathbb{Q}.$ It seems that every element of such type can be expressed as $\mathbb{Q}-$linear combination of $w_{1}, \ldots, w_{n},$ which can be proved by induction on $n$. But somehow, I feel uneasy with this proof. Is my approach valid?

Comment: We may assume that $a_n\neq 0$. Then $\dim (K)=n$ over $\Bbb Q$, so you only need to show that the $w_i$ are linearly independent over $\Bbb Q$. Then they are a basis. But the determinant of the vectors is nonzero, since $a_n$ is nonzero, so you are done.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thank you so much.. I am pretty much done..